# MySQL - Replace spaces from a column in query

Tags: mysql, regex, database, replace

In a query I'm comparing mobile numbers against another (mobile) value in another column.

So far I'm doing this by something like `` ...WHERE `table_one`.`mobile` !=  `table_two`.`mobile ``

The problem is there are identical mobile numbers but separated by different spaces in each of the column ie `07711 123 456` and `07711 123456` therefore returning results when there is a match.

I know how to do this during an update, something like `` update `table` set number = REPLACE( number, ' ', ''); `` but I can't see any examples where this is done in the middle of a query. Perhaps doing a check, placing into a MySQL variable, doing the same with the other mobile in the additional column then comparing the two variables?

Comment: Why don't you TRIM all spaces before comparing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use REPLACE in select query also:

```
select REPLACE( '07711 123 456', ' ', '');
+------------------------------------+
| REPLACE( '07711 123 456', ' ', '') |
+------------------------------------+
| 07711123456                        |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nadeem_MK, thanks for that. I managed to write the query I needed without too much effort.

`` ...WHERE (REPLACE(`tbl_one`.`mobile`, ' ', '')) != (REPLACE(`tbl_two`.`mobile`, ' ', '')) ``

I did try the TRIM function but I could only manage to clear leading or trailing spaces and with two select statements the query was longer than when I used the REPLACE function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that uses regexp to only allows numbers. This way it will remove + - ( ) or any possible characters that is not a integer

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `fn_ShowOnlyNumbers`(str VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strLength INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strChar VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '' ;
  DECLARE retVal VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';

  SET strLength = LENGTH(str);

  WHILE strLength > 0 DO
    SET counter = counter+1;
    SET strChar = SUBSTRING(str,counter,1);
    IF strChar REGEXP('[0-9]') = 1
      THEN SET retVal = CONCAT(retVal,strChar);
    END IF;
    SET strLength = strLength -1;
    SET strChar = NULL;
  END WHILE;
RETURN retVal;
END
```

Then you can simply use the function in your where clause.

```
...WHERE `table_one`.fn_ShowOnlyNumbers(mobile) != `table_two`.fn_ShowOnlyNumbers(mobile)
```